# How can I connect two classes (which don't know eachother) through public interface (C++)

Tags: c++, interface, include

I'm currently working on a project where everything is horribly mixed with everything. Every file include some others etc..
I want to focus a separating part of this spaghetti code into a library which has to be completely independent from the rest of the code.

The current problem is that some functions **FunctionInternal** of my library use some functions **FunctionExternal** declared somewhere else, hence my library is including some other files contained in the project, which is not conform with the requirement "independent from the rest of the code".

It goes without saying that I can't move **FunctionExternal** in my library.

My first idea to tackle this problem was to implement a public interface such as described bellow :

[image]

But I can't get it to work. Is my global pattern a way I could implement it or is there another way, if possible, to interface two functions without including one file in another causing an unwanted dependency.

How could I abstract my ExternalClass so my library would still be independent of the rest of my code ?

Edit 1:

**External.h**

```
#include "lib/InterfaceInternal.h"

class External : public InterfaceInternal {
private:
    void ExternalFunction() {};
public:

    virtual void InterfaceInternal_foo() override {
        ExternalFunction();
    };
 
};
```

**Internal.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "InterfaceInternal.h"

class Internal {

    // how can i received there the InterfaceInternal_foo overrided in External.h ? 

};
```

**InterfaceInternal.h**

```
#pragma once

class InterfaceInternal {
public:
    virtual void InterfaceInternal_foo() = 0;
};
```

Comment: I don't think there's quite enough detail to be able to give a helpful answer. Are you using classes and oo, or free functions?

Comment: Describe what you did, with code examples, which prompted you to say that you can't get it to work.  A pure virtual interface is probably the way to go, so probably something about how you're applying it to your problem is incorrect, or it's not actually suitable.  Either way, nobody can point you in any useful direction until you show a real example.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If yes then there is a way to this I believe.

Comment: @paddy I edited my answer. Thought the diagram would be sufficient enough.

Comment: @doctorlove i am using classes and oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like you suggested, override the internal interface in your external code. Then

> // how can i received there the InterfaceInternal_foo overrided in External.h ?

just pass a pointer/reference to your `class External` that extends `class InterfaceInternal`. Of course your `class Internal` needs to have methods that accept `InterfaceInternal*`.

Or you can just pass the function to your internal interface as an argument. Something around:

```
class InterfaceInternal {
public:
    void InterfaceInternal_foo(std::function<void()> f);
};
```

or more generic:

```
class InterfaceInternal {
public:
    template <typename F>  // + maybe some SFINAE magic, or C++20 concept to make sure it's actually callable
    void InterfaceInternal_foo(F f);
};
```